# How can i trigger event in onlyoffice

Tags: onlyoffice

I am using Onlyoffice 5.0.3. I have altered Onlyoffice code for adding new menu under file menu shown in below image

[image]
 and i have added action script also.

```
 case "approval":{       
      Common.UI.custom({
           closable: false,
           title: "Confirm",
           msg: "Are you sure, do you want to confirm the Approve",
           buttons: ["approve","reject"],
           primary: approve,
           iconCls:"warn",                        
           callback: _.bind(function (e) {                   
                if(e=="approve"){
                 // here i want to trigger event which is given in docEditor Api.
                }  
                else{

                }
           }, this);
     })
     break;
 }
```

my problem has to trigger an event which is given in docEditor API.

Answer (score 0):

by using  `Common.Gateway.eventName();`  I have triggered event, which is given in docEditorAPI.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do it in the current version.
Please contact ONLYOFFICE team directly to discuss all possible ways how this option can be realized.